# Was Alice Perrers a Lollard?

Tags: middle-ages, england

A footnote on page 141-142 of [E S Holt *John De Wycliffe*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/John_de_Wycliffe/4JsHAAAAQAAJ?hl=en)<sup>1</sup>  claims [Alice Perrers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_Perrers) was a [Lollard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lollardy). I know her reputation has been revised recently but is there any evidence for this?

---

1. a footnote on page 141-142 in [google books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/John_de_Wycliffe/4JsHAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%20Alice%20Perrers):

Comment: I don't suppose you could include the passage here in the question, along with some context (like the previous paragraph)? It could help save a lot of time of the people looking into it.

Comment: @T.E.D. I found it on a footnote on page 141-142 in google books: https://www.google.com/books/edition/John_de_Wycliffe/4JsHAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%20Alice%20Perrers

Comment: @AllInOne - All I see there before it cuts off is some referency stuff and "Alice Perrers was". Not exactly informative.

Comment: @T.E.D. click on it, you will be taken to page 141, read the footnote there and follow the note as it continues onto page 142.

Comment: Wow - the syntax of that footnote is astonishing. It is like the author envied the complexity of other languages and tried to incorporate it into English.

Comment: Well, my *suspicion* from reading her bio is that it was a lie written after her death by one of her (many) detractors. There's nothing whatsoever religious in her bio, and it seems like any such scruples would have interfered with what she was good at. Also, it would be a really good nasty thing to say about someone in the 1400's (after she died) but not so much during her life. If I'm reading that footnote right, it seems to be saying just that.

Comment: @T.E.D. my reading of the footnote is something like "why would Walsingham, (who hated Lollards?), have spread lies about Perrers unless Perrers was a Lollard herself".  Seems like slim evidence/speculation either way.

Comment: @AllInOne - Yeah, if that's what the footnote is getting at, its a stretch. Lots of people seemed to have hated her before Wycliffe was even denounced. The woman struck me as rather a Nancy Reagan or Hilary Clinton like figure: A strong woman who gained influence and real power by proximity to the throne, and was widely hated (and then slandered at every opportunity) by a lot of people to try to tear her back down. The kind of person who'd buy into all the Lollard conspiracies floating around seems like the archetype of someone who'd spread slander about her as well.